# Storing 1000s of ids in a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have lots adverts on my site. When a user clicks an advert I log to my database, I want to set a cookie so that this log cannot happen again for the same advert.

I'm aware cookies are insecure but it's fine for this purpose.

What would be the best way of doing this?

1. Store a cookie for each advert with the key of the cookie being the id of the advert, and when a user clicks an ad, check if a cookie exists with the adverts id. Would it be an issue with this because potentially it could create 1000s of cookies?
2. Store one cookie that holds a searliaized array of advert ids, when a user clicks on the advert, the system will unserialise the cookie's array and check if the id is present, if not it will push the current ads id to the cookie's array.
3. Something else?

Comment: You're already logging to a database... isn't it easier to de-duplicate at the database backend rather than forcing that onto the client?

Comment: I was going to suggest #2, yet it depends on how many clicks a user averages.

Comment: 3. Sotre only a uniqe key from a user, and based on that, check, is it in the database. Or get all what is not in the database, or show all, but flag the used

Comment: store some uniqeid in cookie and mange all the clicking in your database.. like id of 12fdf23l123 cliick ad 20 etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies have length limits, and you are limited in the number of cookies you can set.

Keep the log on your server and associate it with the user via an ID token that you store in the cookie.